# Dropdown in Bootstrap V4 with Angular 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Angular 4 using bootstrap V3 to implement Dropdown we are using "Open" class to display the dropdown menu on click. Please suggest is there any class to display the dropdown menu in Bootstrap V4 when we click on dropdown header.

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use in this format

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" 
id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-
expanded="false">
Dropdown button
</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```